# Longitude of the Ecliptic

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate times of moonrise and moonset for a given position on the earth on a particular date. I'm using Vallado's Fundamentals of Astrodynamics and Applications because there is an example in the book that lays out a simplified process. I'm stuck at the point where I'm trying to calculate Longitude of the ecliptic for the Moon. The formula is below where T = -0.013634497.

> λEcliptic = 218.32° + 481,267.8813T + 6.29Sin(134.9 + 477,198.85T) - 1.27Sin(259.2 - 413,335.38T) + 0.66Sin(235.7 + 890,534.23T) + 0.21Sin(269.9 + 954,397.70T) - 0.19Sin(357.5 + 35,999.05T) - 0.11Sin(186.6 + 966,404.05T)

The expected answer is -0.8412457°. However, I'm unable to figure out how to get this answer. My calculations are below:

> 1) 218.32° + 481,267.8813T = -6343.525
>
> 2) 6.29Sin(134.9 + 477,198.85T) = 5.963779
>
> 3) -1.27Sin(259.2 - 413,335.38T) = -0.900843
>
> 4) 0.66Sin(235.7 + 890,534.23T) = -0.292285
>
> 5) 0.21Sin(269.9 + 954,397.70T) = -0.126871
>
> 6) -0.19Sin(357.5 + 35,999.05T) = 0.138211
>
> 7) -0.11Sin(186.6 + 966,404.05T) = 0.054722

Simply adding or subtracting gets me -6338.688731. How can I get the value -0.8412457° from this. My trigonometry is rusty and I'm not sure how to get the right answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The calculations are right, may be the equation is not

Comment: Okay, thanks. At least I know I'm not missing something.

Comment: In fact, based on other sources, the equation is right as well!

Comment: Mods, consider migrating to astronomy.stackexchange.com for more attention.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it had something to do with modulo but I can't figure out how to get the right answer. I'll check out astronomy.stackexchange as well. Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell if you're joking, but "mods" meant "moderators", not "modulo" :)

Comment: http://ccar.colorado.edu/asen5050/projects/projects_2015/Students/Chow_Philip/code/LunarOrbit.m may or may not be helpful, as may this google search https://www.google.com/search?q=218.32++6.29+5.13+259.2+235.7+269.9&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: No, I didn't realize that's what Mod's meant since I figured that working in degrees meant that I needed to reduce it. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Based on the link given by barrycarter, you have the formula for the longitude _of the Moon._ What exactly do you mean by the "longitude of the Moon's ecliptic?" It seems that would be something different.

Comment: It just uses the term "ecliptic". I think that it means when the moon crosses the ascending node.

Comment: I figured out the problem though. The book had the longitude and latitude results switched. I got it to work after that.